# datetime diff negative result?

Tags: php, datetime

I have a php code to use calculate different of two DateTime objects, using date_diff procedure. At times the result is negative but it show positive always.

Code example:

```
  $time1 = new DateTime('01:00:00');
  $time2 = new DateTime('02:00:00');
  $resultTime = date_diff($time1, $time2);
  echo "RESULT: ".$resultTime->format('%h'); // 1
```

Im expecting -1 here, yet I always get positive 1. Is it possible to show the 'real' result, negative or positive?

Comment: Have a look at `$resultTime->invert`, which returns 1 if the difference is negative, or 0 if it is positive. Unfortunately, it is undocumented in the official PHP doc.

Comment: It`s documented here http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Another way - `( $time1 < $time2 ? $sign = '-' : $sign = '' );
  $resultTime = date_diff($time1, $time2);`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`$resultTime->format('%r%H:%i:%s');` is what you're looking for. `%r` prints a minus sign if the difference is negative, or nothing if it is positive. You can also use `$resultTime->invert`, which equals to 1 if the difference is negative.

Comment: A little question. I need the $resultTime a minus sign or positive. But with this value I have to create a new object DateTime that when it's negative show an error message.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully. Do you need to display an error message when the difference is negative? If so, you should do something like `if ($resultTime->invert == 1) { ... }`.