# date difference with negative numbers where appropriate

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the difference in days between the due date of an order and today's date.

I have the following code:

```
function dateDiffInDays($date1, $date2) {
   $diff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
   $result = abs(round($diff / 86400));
   return $result;
}
```

When I call the function, `$date1` is today and `$date2` is the due date.

This works well, however if an order is overdue, that's to say `$date2` is before `$date1`, the function doesn't return a negative number - meaning that the order looks as if it is not overdue.

I have attempted to use an if statement within the function, to multiply the `$result` by -1 `$date1` is greater than `$date2`, but this returns strange results and feels a bit hacky.

I am therefore looking for help in changing this function so that it returns negative values, if `$date1` is before `$date2`

Comment: The part of the code that's preventing negative numbers is [abs()](https://php.net/abs). But doing custom date maths is almost never fully correct (for instance, next Sunday won't have 86400 seconds in most Europe). You have native functionality available: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 1):

Use datetime object.

See this answer, it does exactly what you need: [datetime diff negative result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503824/datetime-diff-negative-result)